# Angular2 http get request returns html

Tags: json, angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to send this test data from my node js server to front end.

```
router.get('/abc', (req, res) => {
  return res.json({
   test: "success!"
  });
});
```

In my service component:

```
private url = "http://localhost:4200/auth/abc";

getTitles() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

What I expected was my test object but ends up getting my index.html file in string format: (that's what I get when I use console.log(res)).

```
<"!DOCTYPE html">...<"/html">
```

FYI, I'm using cors module in node js app.

plus(my angular-cli.json file) :

```
 {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "angular-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure, but when I do `res.json`, I do `{ "asd": "asd" }`, not `{ asd: "asd" }`. not sure how much it helps, but you can try

Comment: Thank you for comment Giora Guttsait but it didin't helped me ..

Comment: You're pointing back at the webpack dev server and not the server with your api endpoint. Did you set up a proxy on the dev server? If not then where is the the api running? Point to there.

Comment: Neil, I'm currently using angular-cli and I want to ask you how can I set up a proxy setting for this case(angular-cli.json)!

Comment: Have you tried calling "http://localhost:4200/auth/abc" with a rest client or even just visiting the URL in your browser (since it's a GET)? Does it return JSON or HTML? If it returns html, you'll want to debug the API.

Comment: I got "cannot match any url segments error" cause it's not defined in my 
angular-routing module..

Comment: Here's a link showing how to do reverse proxy: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy

Comment: You mean try adding proxy.conf.json and add these lines:

    {
        "/auth/abc": {
            "target": "http://localhost:4200",
            "secure": false
      } 
     }

right?

Comment: I get this line: Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:4200/auth/abc

Comment: Can you try private url = "/auth/abc";

Comment: I also tried it before Yeysides and it didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your routing, based on what I can see, your express is waiting for `"http://localhost:4200/abc"` to return `"success!"` , but inside your Angular2 you're trying to hit `"http://localhost:4200/auth/abc";`.

Try hitting your url directly to see if you can get the result ,

try putting this in the browser :

```
  http://localhost:4200/abc
```

If you get your JSON back , your router is good, you just need to fix the url in your app.

Comment: Sorry Milad, I didn't mentioned above but I'm using backend router named as 'auth', so it's not the case..

Comment: So you can hit that URL outside of Angular2?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of Angular2", milad?

Comment: I mean when you try putting  this : http://localhost:4200/auth/abc ,  in your browser, do you get the response you're looking for ?

Comment: I'm getting "no url segment" error because it's not part of my angular route.

Comment: And what makes me confused is that "post" approach goes perfect but "get" doesn't.

Comment: Your api and Angular app should be running in different ports, you should be able to hit your URL without Angular2

Comment: Yes , because somewhere in your nodeJS code, you're redirecting all the get methods to index.html ( Angular)

Comment: then 
"app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});"

These lines may cause problem.

Comment: Wow, now I'm getting some clue about what's happening!

Comment: Yeap , but the best approach is to have your nodeJS backend to run in a seperate port

Comment: Then what I supposed to do?
Remove those two lines and execute both ng serve and node server.js
at the same time??

Comment: if you just comment `app.get('*', `  this line, that will fix the whole issue

Comment: Yes exactly, you need to use ng serve for angular, and your server.js for your server code

Comment: You mean " app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));"
doesn't matter?

Comment: No, I mean app.get('*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html')); });"

Comment: lovely! I'll try it!